# How to call action from checkbox input using tag helpers

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, checkbox, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

If I want to call controller action using input of type image I can do it like:

```
<form method="post">
    <button asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">Click Me</button>
    <input type="image" src="..." alt="Or Click Me" asp-controller="Home" 
                                asp-action="Index">
</form>
```

**Is it possible to do something similar with input of type checkbox using tag helpers like this:**

```
<input type="checkbox" asp-for="@Model.Property" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="DoSomething" asp-route-propertyId="@Model.Id" class="form-control" />
```

? Or if I must write own custom tag helper for this?

Code below also does not work.

```
<input type="checkbox" asp-for="@Model.Property" onclick="@Url.Action("DoSomething", "Home", new { propertyId= Model.Id })" class="form-control" />
```

Edit:
Currentyly I found solution as follow:

```
<input type="checkbox" asp-for="@Model.Property" onclick="triggerLink(@Model.Property)" class="form-control" />
```

than I add following script:

```
function triggerLink(Property) {
    var theUrl = '@Url.Action("DoSomething", "Home")?propertyId=' + Property;
    window.location = theUrl;
}
```

It's working but I am still looking for a solution with tag helpers.

Comment: Actually,I suggest that use js is more easy.Input tag helper is a whole entity.But when the type is checkbox,`asp-controller` and `asp-action` do not make sense.To custom the tag helper is a complex work.By the way,it seems you want to pass the property to the backend.I think just use submit input is ok.If you just want to pass single property,try to use `asp-route-{value}` like below:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/built-in/anchor-tag-helper?view=aspnetcore-3.1#asp-route-value

Comment: Thanks for comment. The best solution for mew will be write own tag helper. Now I stay with triggerLink JS function as in my question.